# How to add consumerGroup for a topic in kafka using Shopify/sarama golang library?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

In the sarama library there is an option to initialize NewConsumerGroup but how to hook it hook i t up to NewConumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NewConsumerGroup` creates its own Consumer, so there's nothing for you to hook it to

Source: https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/main/consumer_group.go#L105